# Swift Parameter Packs: Is there a way to spread a tuple into the arguments of a function?

Tags: swift, swift5.9

Consider the following code from a dependency injection package:

```
func register<T, each A>(
  _ type: T.Type = T.self,
  tags: AnyHashable...,
  lifetime: Lifetime = .transient,
  factory: @escaping (any Resolver, repeat each A) throws -> T
) -> Key {
  let thunk = { (r: any Resolver, args: (repeat each A)) throws -> T in
    try factory(r, repeat each args)
  }
  return register(type, tags: Set(tags), lifetime: lifetime, factory: thunk)
}
```

This fails to compile. The error is:

**INTERNAL ERROR**: feature not implemented: reabstraction of pack values.

Now, I know why this is happening. Inside of `thunk` I attempt to do something fancy. We've told it that the type of `args` is `(repeat each A)`, i.e., a tuple generated from the parameter pack types. But, in the body of `thunk` I say `try factory(r, repeat each args)`. I was crossing my fingers that Swift 5.9 would be smart enough to "unravel" the tuple it had just created from the parameter pack, but it looks like this (superb) feature has not yet been implemented, if it ever will be. This means I'm forced to use the old style of multiple overloads with different numbers of parameters.

Does anyone know a workaround for this? Is there some clever way to spread a tuple in Swift 5.9?

Comment: Can you show the signature of `register` that you call inside the currently shown `register` function? Surely it's a different function, and I can't see why you need `thunk` with just the code you showed.

Comment: @Sweeper Sure. You can find the signature of the other `register` here: https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/blob/master/Sources/Guise/Registrar/Registrar.swift. And you can find the overloads I'm trying to replace with a single packed function here:  https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/blob/master/Sources/Guise/Registrar/Registrar%2BSync.swift.

Comment: The signatures for `SyncFactory` and `AsyncFactory` are here: https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/blob/master/Sources/Guise/Common/Factory.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing all tests after changing function and types signatures:

```
public typealias SyncFactory<T, each A> = (any Resolver, repeat each A) throws -> T
```

```
func register<T, each A>(_ type: T.Type = T.self, tags: AnyHashable..., lifetime: Lifetime = .transient, factory: @escaping (any Resolver, repeat each A) throws -> T) -> Key {
    let factory: SyncFactory<T, repeat each A> = { (r: any Resolver, arg: repeat each A) in
        try factory(r, repeat each arg)
    }
    return register(type, tags: Set(tags), lifetime: lifetime, factory: factory)
}
```

Here is the [pull request](https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/pull/5) with all the changes to SyncFactory APIs.

Comment: Right. The difference is that `(repeat each A)` produces a tuple, which is what I need. The `register` function called in the last line expects a single type as its second parameter. To see this, take a look at https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/blob/master/Sources/Guise/Registrar/Registrar%2BSync.swift. These are the overloads I'm trying to replace with a single function.

So the problem is that your solution won't work in my situation.

Comment: I was able to make function works by changing the SyncFactory implementation to this: `typealias SyncFactory<T, each A> = (any Resolver, repeat each A) throws -> T`. Also by changing protocol requirement to this signature `func register<T, each A>(_ type: T.Type, tags: Set<AnyHashable>, lifetime: Lifetime, factory: @escaping SyncFactory<T, repeat each A>) -> Key`. I added couple fatalErrors so haven't revisited all the sources but was able to have one `register`  function in the end.

Comment: Not sure if this will work after changing all the code without breaking existing codebases though...

Comment: Would you mind submitting a pull request so I can take a look at your changes? I'd need to compile and run the unit tests to see if everything works.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/pull/4 . All tests passed

Comment: Here is the pull with fixed indentation and support for sync and async factory. Tests passed. https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/pull/5

Comment: Thanks! I've been extremely busy with work and haven't had the chance to examine it closely yet, but I will.